# quicksort function does not work (in c)

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I cannot get my code to work! I am trying to implement the quick sort algorithm with linked lists. I keep getting memory leaks problems and cannot resolve them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memcheck.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

node *quicksort(node *list);
int ListLength (node *list);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  node *list;
  node *sorted_list;
  int i;
  int intArg = 0; /* number of integer arguments */
  int print = 1;
  /* if -q is found anywhere then we are going 
   * to change the behavior of the program */
   if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-q] number1 number2 ... \
    (must enter at least one argument)\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1); }
  for ( i = 1 ; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-q") == 0) {
      print = 0; }
    else {
      list = create_node(atoi(argv[i]), list); /* memory allocation is taken care of */
      intArg++; } }
  if (intArg == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-q] number1 number2 ...\
  (at least one of the input arguments must be an integer)\n", argv[0]); 
    exit(1); }
  sorted_list = quicksort(list);
  free_list(list);
  list = sorted_list;
  if (print == 1) {
    print_list(list); }
  print_memory_leaks();
  return 0; } 

node *quicksort(node *list) {
  node *less=NULL, *more=NULL, *next, *temp=NULL, *end, *listCopy;
  node *pivot = list;
  listCopy = copy_list(list);
  if (ListLength(list) <= 1) {
    return listCopy; }
  else {
    next = listCopy->next;
    listCopy = next;
    /* split into two */
    temp = listCopy;
    while(temp != NULL) {
      next = temp->next;
      if (temp->data < pivot->data) {
        temp->next = less;
        less = temp; }
      else {
        temp->next = more;
        more = temp; }
      temp = next; }
    less = quicksort(less);
    more = quicksort(more); }

  /* appending the results */
  if (less != NULL) {
          end = less;
          while (end->next != NULL) {
                  end = end->next; }
          pivot->next = more;
          end->next = pivot;
          return less; }
  else {
          pivot->next = more;
          return pivot; } }

int ListLength (node *list) {
  node *temp = list;
  int i=0;
  while(temp!=NULL) {
    i++; 
    temp=temp->next; }
  return i; }


/*Code from the libraries */


node * 
create_node(int data, node *n) {
    node *result = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                "Terminating program.\n");
        exit(1); }
    result->data = data;  /* Fill in the new node with the given value. */
    result->next = n;
    return result; }

void
free_list(node *list) {
    node *n;     /* a single node of the list */
    while (list != NULL) {
        n = list;
        list = list->next;
     /*
     * 'n' now points to the first element of the list, while
     * 'list' now points to everything but the first element.
     * Since nothing points to 'n', it can be freed.
     */

        free(n); } }

node *
copy_list(node *list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return list; }
    else {
        node *new_list;
        new_list = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_list == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                    "Terminating program.\n");
            exit(1); }
        new_list->data = list->data;
        new_list->next = copy_list(list->next);
        return new_list; } }

/* other available methods are append_lists, reverse_list */
```

Comment: As a side note, don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer to serve you in all such circumstances: you say you keep getting memory leaks but cannot resolve them. Have you tried using a tool to attempt to catch memory errors, though? Valgrind, for example, will catch most failures to free memory, use after free errors, etc. It is well worth learning how to use it.

(As an aside, you say that you know you're getting memory leaks, but you do not explain how you know you are getting them.)

Comment: print_memory_leaks() prints the memory leaks after execution on terminal

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that it uses an uninitialized variable `list`.  It needs to be assigned NULL prior to the first call to `create_node`.

**Edit** I was thinking `quicksort` was leaking the input list in some cases ... and now I am less sure of that; it is not completely clear what it is doing.  I would have to step through it with a debugger to follow it.  I'm fairly certain that it should *not* be calling `copy_list`.  There is no reason for it to duplicate the input list. It should be partitioning into the two groups and then reassembling the two portions and just returning the re-ordered original list.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the second statement. I set pivot = listCopy and initialized list to NULL. Now my code works in terms of printing the sorted list but afterwards it still gives memory leak problems

Comment: @DanP.  If you assigned pivot = listCopy, then it is definitely leaking the input list on the less/more quicksort calls.  I don't think you should call copy_list at all inside the quicksort function.  (And then, subsequently, you need to remove the free_list call that is immediately after the main quicksort call.

Comment: not if you want the original to remian unchanged then you need to make a copy

Comment: @DanP.:  If you want to preserve the original, then you have to make a copy **before** calling quicksort.  It is recursive; it can't be making copies in the middle of the sorting; that leads to leaks.